# Bottom-aligned paragraph in rtf template

Tags: ms-word, reporting, rtf, bi-publisher, infobip

I need to generate a report with a specific block of text **at the bottom of one page** from `.rtf` template using **Oracle BI Publisher**.

I've tried many ways of positioning text in Word and other stuff, but `OBIP` ignores them all,
besides, **Oracle** doesn't give any access to its support forum to me.

My **attempts**:

- splitting template into sections with brakes (continuous one, page break doesn't suit for me) to make a unique footer
- using shapes/text boxes with aligning/text wrapping/removing 'move with text' tick
- using footnotes
- using MS Word fields with `ctrl+F9` to make a unique footer like: `IF PAGE = 2 "text"`
- passing an `XLM` model with a tag having `HTML` code like: `position:fixed; bottom:0`

**Example** of what I'd like to see in my report:

> ... Body text of page №4

> Footnote at the bottom of page №4

> Body text of page №5 ...

Comment: Please post the code  you're having trouble with. In any event, your issue seems to concern the failure to use a properly-designed template for your project rather than a programming one, per se.

Comment: @macropod The problem is not with the code, I just don't see a way of using Footnotes with OBIP.
I am using BIPublisherDesktop64 v.12.214 with MS Word 2016.
I prepare an .rtf template, load an .xml sample (successfully), preview a report locally (pdf/doc - doesn't matter) and have a problem with Footnote, example is here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L4EZ_H-TkgoUbMJ_deX2dzbA0oWHPh4F/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116809044616679320376&rtpof=true&sd=true